# prevent Html.Action with JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, asynchronous, progressive-enhancement

Quick question guys, I have this on my view

```
    <div class="product_list">
        @Html.Action("GetProducts", "Products")
    </div>
```

and the controller is simply

```
public ActionResult GetProducts(string country, string currency, int category){
    var viewModel = new ProductsViewModel{
        Products = _proxy.GetProducts(country, currency, category, page)};

    return PartialView(viewModel);
}
```

Then the GetProducts View just renders each product in a foreach loop

I would like to prevent this to happen if JS is enabled and with JQuery call te service asynchronously. Something like

```
$(".product_list").SOMETHING(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    ...
 });
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead :

```
$(".product_list a").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // code to be executed.
 });
```

**Edit :**  *As per @kooshka comment*

When JS disabled :

```
<div class="product_list">
    <!-- Will execute when JS is disabled in browser -->
    <noscript>
        @Html.Action("GetProducts", "Products")
    </noscript>
</div>
```

When JS enabled than the script code should be :

```
$(".product_list").SOMETHING(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(".product_list").html('@Html.Action("GetProducts", "Products")');
    ...
});
```

Good Luck !!

Comment: There is no click there. It's an Action to render a PartialView

Comment: @kooshka, do you want to execute this statement on certain condition in js?

Comment: the only condition is for js to be enabled. the partial view is rendered sync on the server, i want to prevent that, load the page without that products block and load it async with jquery instead

Comment: @kooshka, i have updated my answer. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: The <noscript> tag is what I was looking for. Thanks